# Show the last index in an array when I click (in an array that continues to be updated)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, indexing, array.prototype.map

I am near the end of creating my application.

So it is for banks accounts where they ask you to give the **first letter** of your password, then for example **fourth**, etc.

I'm tired of counting on my own so I created this app.

But there is the last bug that I don't know how to fix.

So when I press "1" I get "1 - H", 
and then when I press "4" I want to get:

"1 - H" (clicked before)
"4 - X" (clicked just now)

but instead, I get:

"4 - X" (clicked just now)
"4 - X" (clicked just now)

So it is caused by the way `handleResults()` function works inside my `Input` component, but for now it is my only concept how to approach this...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';

import './style.css';

import Buttons from '../Buttons';
import Results from '../Results';

class Input extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      password: 'Hh9Xzke2ayzcEUPHuIfS',
      selectedButtons: [],
    };
    this.handleButtonSelectTwo = this.handleButtonSelectTwo.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange(pass) {
    this.setState({ password: pass });
  }

  handleButtonSelectTwo(selected) {
    this.setState({
      selectedButtons: [...this.state.selectedButtons, selected],
    });
  }

  handleResults() {
    return this.state.selectedButtons.map(el => (
      <Results key={el} appState={this.state} />
    ));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="Input-textfield">
          <TextField
            hintText="Paste your password here to begin"
            value={this.state.password}
            onChange={event => this.handleInputChange(event.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Buttons
            handleButtonSelectOne={this.handleButtonSelectTwo}
            array={this.state.password.length}
          />
          {this.handleResults()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Input;
```

and here is `Results` component code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';

import Avatar from 'material-ui/Avatar';
import List from 'material-ui/List/List';
import ListItem from 'material-ui/List/ListItem';

import './style.css';

const style = {
  avatarList: {
    position: 'relative',
    left: -40,
  },
  avatarSecond: {
    position: 'relative',
    top: -40,
    left: 40,
  },
};

class Results extends Component {
  resultsEngine(arg) {
    const { selectedButtons, password } = this.props.appState;
    const passwordArray = password.split('').map(el => el);

    const lastSelectedButton = _.last(selectedButtons);
    const passwordString = passwordArray[_.last(selectedButtons) - 1];

    if (arg === 0) {
      return lastSelectedButton;
    }

    if (arg === 1) {
      return passwordString;
    }

    return null;
  }
  render() {
    if (this.props.appState.selectedButtons.length > 0) {
      return (
        <div className="test">
          <List style={style.avatarList}>
            <ListItem
              disabled
              leftAvatar={<Avatar>{this.resultsEngine(0)}</Avatar>}
            />
            <ListItem
              style={style.avatarSecond}
              disabled
              leftAvatar={<Avatar>{this.resultsEngine(1)}</Avatar>}
            />
          </List>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return <div />;
  }
}

export default Results;
```

Anyone has an idea how should I change my code inside `handleResults()` function to achieve my goal? Any help with solving that problem will be much appreciated.

`Buttons` component code:

```
import React from 'react';

import OneButton from '../OneButton';

const Buttons = props => {
  const arrayFromInput = props.array;
  const buttonsArray = [];

  for (let i = 1; i <= arrayFromInput; i++) {
    buttonsArray.push(i);
  }

  const handleButtonSelectZero = props.handleButtonSelectOne;

  const allButtons = buttonsArray.map(el => (
    <OneButton key={el} el={el} onClick={handleButtonSelectZero} />
  ));

  if (arrayFromInput > 0) {
    return <div>{allButtons}</div>;
  }

  return <div />;
};

export default Buttons;
```

And `OneButton` code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

const style = {
  button: {
    margin: 2,
    padding: 0,
    minWidth: 1,
  },
};

class OneButton extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { disabled: false };
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({ disabled: !this.state.disabled });
    this.props.onClick(this.props.el);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <RaisedButton
        disabled={this.state.disabled}
        key={this.props.el}
        label={this.props.el}
        style={style.button}
        onClick={() => this.handleClick()}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default OneButton;
```

Comment: We are going to need to see your Buttons component to be able to trace the `selected` parameter going into the handleButtonSelectTwo(selected) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your resultsEngine function in the Results component you are specifying that you always want the `_.last(selectedButtons)` to be used. This is what it is doing, hence you always see the last button clicked. What you actually want is the index of that iteration to show.

```
const lastSelectedButton = selectedButtons[this.props.index];
const passwordString = passwordArray[selectedButtons[this.props.index]];
```

To get an index you have to create and pass one in, so create it when you map over the selected Buttons in the handleResults function in your Input component.

```
handleResults() {
    return this.state.selectedButtons.map((el, index) => (
      <Results key={el} appState={this.state} index={index} />
    ));
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works and I understand that solution! Everything is clear. Perfect answer!

Comment: Glad I could help. You index for the length value is one off I think, clicking on the last button comes up blank. But that is a minor fix, I'm sure you can handle it.

Comment: Yea, I just changed it to: const passwordString = passwordArray[selectedButtons[this.props.index] - 1];